# Cannot partition windows on bootcamp (NOT time machine issue)

Tags: mac, hard-drive, bootcamp, windows

Apologies if I have gotten this in the wrong place. It's been a long few days.

Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4
System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)

So a while back, I decided to install windows on bootcamp. I did it, and then I needed to reinstall, so I wiped it and began to do it again. It's been an absolute disaster.

First, I've tried like 100 different things. I tried boot camp assistant, it says > **The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned.**

> You must have at least 40 GB of free space available.

This is clearly false since I have 103 gb available. Moreover, I have turned off time machine and deleted old snapshots as every single website has told me. I was thinking maybe I need to defrag, but apparently, defragging doesn't do anything on an SSD, which I believe I have.

Never mind, I thought, I'll try to repair everything on disk utility. Did nothing.

Tried to partition using disk utility. I created a partition called "windows" under MS-DOS (FAT) and gave it 58 gb. This is the maximum size that I'm allowed to drag the circle (which makes no sense since I should have 103 gb left, but whatever). When I did this, I received the following information (Freezing on "Applying changes to “APPLE SSD SM0256G Media”"):

> Running operation 1 of 2: Add “windows” by splitting “Macintosh HD”…
>   Aligning shrink delta to 58,658,160,640 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 192,132,276,224 bytes
>   Determined the minimum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 192,132,276,224 bytes
>   Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk1
>   The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk0s2
>   Verifying storage system
>   Using live mode.
>   Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l /dev/disk0s2
>   Checking volume.
>   Checking the container superblock.
>   Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
>   Checking the space manager.
>   Checking the object map.
>   Checking the APFS volume superblock.
>   Checking the object map.
>   Checking the fsroot tree.
>   Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
>   Checking the extent ref tree.
>   Checking the snapshots.
>   Checking snapshot 1 of 1.
>   warning: apfs_num_files (1219357) is not valid (1219351)
>   Checking the APFS volume superblock.
>   Checking the object map.
>   Checking the fsroot tree.
>   Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
>   Checking the extent ref tree.
>   Checking the snapshots.
>   Checking the APFS volume superblock.
>   Checking the object map.
>   Checking the fsroot tree.
>   Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
>   Checking the extent ref tree.
>   Checking the snapshots.
>   Checking the APFS volume superblock.
>   Checking the object map.
>   Checking the fsroot tree.
>   Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
>   Checking the extent ref tree.
>   Checking the snapshots.
>   Verifying allocated space.
>   The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK.
>   Storage system check exit code is 0.
>   Shrinking APFS Physical Store disk0s2 from 250,790,436,864 to 192,132,276,224 bytes
>   Shrinking APFS data structures
>   APFS Container Resize error code is 49153
>   A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures.
>   Operation failed…

I also would like to note a few other things:
1: I have been  trying to do this for a while. I even got bootcamp like halfway through (disk image accepted and everything) and then it seemed to stop working sending me on a long path to figure out how to delete the useless partition 
2: My mac has been running a bit slowly recently (like when I restart, it spends a ton of time with just a little bit of the bar not loaded)
3: I spilled coffee on my computer a while back, but nothing seemed particularly wrong for quite some time - I highly suspect that this is NOT the issue.
4: If you need any more information please let me know
5: I have an entire hard drive full of backups, so if I need to I can completely reformat. However, I'm not sure exactly how licenses and stuff carry over.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: I figured out how to solve the problem. Apparently, it was an issue with time machine, but I was just using the wrong string of code. I called apple and they gave it to me. Unfortunately, I can't remember the exact string, but I'll post it if I can find it. I may delete the post just so there's no more confusion though.